# Editing Game Audio Disk

Tags: audio, disk-image

I have a very old game from 90s. the disk contains the setup files only. But When I right-click on it, It seems it is a multimedia disk which contains in-game musics and I can play them track by track using windows media player.

When I create an image of this disk, there is no audio or something similar in it, just an exe files and some archive ones (which also contains strange file formats in it) and some dlls.

so where is the audios? I can rip them using some tools, but I need to know why it is like this? why there is no audio or I can not edit the image to for example removing some of those audios from the disk.

Comment: [Mixed mode CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_Mode_CD)?

Comment: What game is this? I remember Might and Magic 6-8 had something similar.

Answer (score -1):

a) "The 90s" isn't "very old."
b) how did you "create an image" - if done correctly there should be no difference between the image and the disc, and so you should be able to mount/play in exactly the same manner
c) you cannot generally manipulate ("edit the image") image files.
d) Better software will be able to grab the audio. Whether this is done by "ripping" or simple file transfer/encoding depends on the disc.